# L1/L2 regularization in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function, regularized

How do I add L1/L2 regularization in PyTorch without manually computing it?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

See the [documentation](http://pytorch.org/docs/optim.html#torch.optim.Adagrad). Add a `weight_decay` parameter to the optimizer for L2 regularization.

Comment: Adagrad is an optimization technique, I am talking about regularization. Can you give me a concrete example with L1 and L2 loss?

Comment: Ya, the L2 regularisation is mysteriously added in the Optimization functions because loss functions are used during Optimization. You can find the discussion here https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/simple-l2-regularization/139/3

Comment: I have some branches using L2 loss, so this is not useful. (I have different loss functions)

Comment: What if I want use L1 or some other loss for regularization?

Comment: @mrgloom you can implement that yourself. It is not included with the optimizers.

Answer (score 96):

Use `weight_decay > 0` for L2 regularization:

```
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-4, weight_decay=1e-5)
```

Comment: In SGD optimizer, L2 regularization can be obtained by `weight_decay`. But `weight_decay` and L2 regularization is different for Adam optimizer. More can be read here: https://openreview.net/pdf?id=rk6qdGgCZ

Comment: @Ashish your comment is correct that `weight_decay` and L2 regularization is different but in the case of PyTorch's implementation of Adam, they actually implement L2 regularization instead of true weight decay. Note that the weight decay term is applied to the gradient before the optimizer step [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/40d1f77384672337bd7e734e32cb5fad298959bd/torch/optim/_functional.py#L94)

Comment: How about L1 regularization?

Answer (score 49):

Previous answers, while technically correct, are inefficient performance wise and are not too modular (hard to apply on a per-layer basis, as provided by, say, `keras` layers).

### PyTorch L2 implementation

**Why PyTorch implemented `L2` inside `torch.optim.Optimizer` instances?**

Let's take a look at [`torch.optim.SGD` source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/optim/_functional.py#L143) (currently as functional optimization procedure), especially this part:

```
for i, param in enumerate(params):
    d_p = d_p_list[i]
    # L2 weight decay specified HERE!
    if weight_decay != 0:
        d_p = d_p.add(param, alpha=weight_decay)
```

- One can see, that `d_p` (derivative of parameter, gradient) is modified and re-assigned for faster computation (not saving the temporary variables)
- It has `O(N)` complexity without any complicated math like `pow`
- **It does not involve `autograd` extending the graph without any need**

Compare that to `O(n)` `**2` operations, addition and also taking part in backpropagation.

### Math

Let's see `L2` equation with `alpha` regularization factor (same could be done for L1 ofc):

[image: L2]

If we take derivative of any loss with `L2` regularization w.r.t. parameters `w` (it is independent of loss), we get:

[image: L2 deriv]

**So it is simply an addition of `alpha * weight` for gradient of every weight!** And this is exactly what PyTorch does above!

### L1 Regularization layer

Using this (and some PyTorch magic), we can come up with quite generic L1 regularization layer, but let's look at first derivative of `L1` first (`sgn` is signum function, returning `1` for positive input and `-1` for negative, `0` for `0`):

[image: L1 derivative]

Full code with `WeightDecay` interface located in [torchlayers third party library](https://github.com/szymonmaszke/torchlayers/blob/master/torchlayers/regularization.py#L150) providing stuff like regularizing only weights/biases/specifically named paramters (**disclaimer: I'm the author**), but the essence of the idea outlined below (see comments):

```
class L1(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, module, weight_decay):
        super().__init__()
        self.module = module
        self.weight_decay = weight_decay

        # Backward hook is registered on the specified module
        self.hook = self.module.register_full_backward_hook(self._weight_decay_hook)

    # Not dependent on backprop incoming values, placeholder
    def _weight_decay_hook(self, *_):
        for param in self.module.parameters():
            # If there is no gradient or it was zeroed out
            # Zeroed out using optimizer.zero_grad() usually
            # Turn on if needed with grad accumulation/more safer way
            # if param.grad is None or torch.all(param.grad == 0.0):

            # Apply regularization on it
            param.grad = self.regularize(param)

    def regularize(self, parameter):
        # L1 regularization formula
        return self.weight_decay * torch.sign(parameter.data)

    def forward(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Simply forward and args and kwargs to module
        return self.module(*args, **kwargs)
```

Read more about hooks [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65011884/understanding-backward-hooks) or respective PyTorch docs if needed.

And usage is also pretty simple (should work with gradient accumulation and and PyTorch layers):

```
layer = L1(torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3))
```

Comment: Would you like to make a new tag for `torchlayers` and release it with `L1` and `L2` because they are still missing in version 0.1.1 released more that 1 year ago?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin could you try the nightly release? It should be there although not thoroughly tested as of yet, new release is planned in the upcoming 2 months (together with other libraries)

Comment: Nightly has `L1` and `L2`, thank you. There is a warning though `~/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:785: UserWarning: Using a non-full backward hook when outputs are generated by different autograd Nodes is deprecated and will be removed in future versions. This hook will be missing some grad_output. Please use register_full_backward_hook to get the documented behavior.`

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin See [this PR](https://github.com/szymonmaszke/torchlayers/pull/12), you can update yours version accordingly (if tests pass it will be released today @ 00:00 GMT).

Comment: This looks great - I would like to ask: how come you assign the output of reguralize(param) to the gradient instead of of adding regularize(param) to the gradient? Does the necessary addition happen automatically?

Comment: @stochasticmrfox If we were to add we might accumulate it during gradient accumulation (during each backward). What we want is to keep either `-1` or `1` until the optimizer uses this feedback. Otherwise it could grow to, say -16 for 16 steps of gradient accumulation.

Comment: https://github.com/torch/optim/pull/41#issuecomment-73935805, but it does not exactly support your assertion.

Comment: _"L1 regularization is not implemented as it does not actually induce sparsity"_: do you mean that this is a particular limitation of neural networks/pytorch? This is not true for vanilla lasso implementation with coordinate descent. I implemented it from scratch and the theoretical result for L1/Lasso regularisation works in practice without manually using a threshold to round coefficients to zero.

Comment: @phydev - yes, was inteded as more of a sidenote for neural network specifically (not for lasso regression), will remove it as it might be confusing for users and not substantiated by any source. See Kevin Yin comment above as it is somewhat related.

Comment: I think your side note is important actually, just wanted to clarify. I tried different implementations of L1-regularization in pytorch and I thought that they were wrong because I couldn't reach sparsity, so it was good to come across your answer. It's not clear to me why this happens thought, but I suspect it is related with the minimisation procedure that is quite different from Lasso. Thanks for your great answer btw, I have been using your L1 layer.

Answer (score 29):

For L2 regularization,

```
l2_lambda = 0.01
l2_reg = torch.tensor(0.)

for param in model.parameters():
    l2_reg += torch.norm(param)

loss += l2_lambda * l2_reg
```

References:

- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-does-one-implement-weight-regularization-l1-or-l2-manually-without-optimum/7951.
- http://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html?highlight=norm#torch.norm.

Comment: Shouldn't one need to exclude non-trainable parameters?

Comment: `torch.norm` is taking 2-norm here, not the square of the 2-norm. So I think the norm should be squared to get a correct regularization.

Comment: without requires_grad and use += would cause error. This works for me:

l2_reg = torch.tensor(0., requires_grad=True)
l2_reg = l2_reg + torch.norm(param)

Comment: Warning: `torch.norm` is [deprecated](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.norm.html).

Answer (score 25):

### L2 regularization out-of-the-box

Yes, pytorch [optimizers](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html) have a parameter called `weight_decay` which corresponds to the L2 regularization factor:

```py
sgd = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), weight_decay=weight_decay)
```

### L1 regularization implementation

There is no analogous argument for L1, however this is straightforward to implement manually:

```py
loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)
l1_lambda = 0.001
l1_norm = sum(torch.linalg.norm(p, 1) for p in model.parameters())

loss = loss + l1_lambda * l1_norm
```

The equivalent manual implementation of L2 would be:

```
l2_reg = sum(p.pow(2).sum() for p in model.parameters())
```

Source: [*Deep Learning with PyTorch*](https://pytorch.org/assets/deep-learning/Deep-Learning-with-PyTorch.pdf) (8.5.2)

Answer (score 18):

for L1 regularization and include `weight` only:

```py
l1_reg = torch.tensor(0., requires_grad=True)

for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    if 'weight' in name:
        l1_reg = l1_reg + torch.linalg.norm(param, 1)

total_loss = total_loss + 10e-4 * l1_reg
```

Comment: Warning: `torch.norm` is [deprecated](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.norm.html).

Answer (score 6):

Interesting `torch.norm` is slower on CPU and faster on GPU vs. direct approach.

```
import torch
x = torch.randn(1024,100)
y = torch.randn(1024,100)

%timeit torch.sqrt((x - y).pow(2).sum(1))
%timeit torch.norm(x - y, 2, 1)
```

Out:

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 910 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.76 ms per loop
```

On the other hand:

```
import torch
x = torch.randn(1024,100).cuda()
y = torch.randn(1024,100).cuda()

%timeit torch.sqrt((x - y).pow(2).sum(1))
%timeit torch.norm(x - y, 2, 1)
```

Out:

```
10000 loops, best of 3: 50 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 26 µs per loop
```

Comment: Confirmed that on my end as well. torch.norm is about 60% slower in this example.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, GPU calculations are nonblocking, this means that timeit will not work correctly, because calculations are still in progress on GPU even after CPU (where the timeit happens)  takes control. To get the correct timing, you must synchronize before stopping timer.

Comment: If you time it correctly, you will see torch.norm is almost twice as fast as sqrt approach (by using torch.cuda.synchronize before stop timer)

Answer (score 2):

To extend on the good answers: As it was said, L2 norm added to the loss is equivalent to weight decay **iff** you use plain SGD without momentum. Otherwise, e.g. with Adam, it is not exactly the same. The AdamW paper [1] pointed out that weight decay is actually more stable. That is why you should use weight decay, which is an option to the optimizer. And consider using [`AdamW`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.AdamW.html) instead of `Adam`.

Also note, you probably don't want weight decay on all parameters (`model.parameters()`), but only on a subset. See here for examples:

- [Weight decay in the optimizers is a bad idea (especially with BatchNorm)](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/weight-decay-in-the-optimizers-is-a-bad-idea-especially-with-batchnorm/16994)
- [Weight decay only for weights of nn.Linear and nn.Conv*](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/weight-decay-only-for-weights-of-nn-linear-and-nn-conv/114348)
- [Karpathy minGPT code](https://github.com/karpathy/minGPT/blob/3ed14b2cec0dfdad3f4b2831f2b4a86d11aef150/mingpt/model.py#L136)

[1] [Decoupled Weight Decay Regularization (AdamW), 2017](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.05101)