# How to add L1 Regularization to PyTorch NN Model?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, loss-function

When searching for ways to implement L1 regularization in PyTorch Models, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641976/in-pytorch-how-to-add-l1-regularizer-to-activations/47196174), which is now 2 years old so i was wondering if theres anything new on this topic?

I also found [this recent approach](https://github.com/dizam92/pyTorchReg/blob/master/src/regularization/regularizer.py) of dealing with the missing l1 function. However I don't understand how to use it for a basic NN as shown below.

```
class FFNNModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim, hidden_dim, dropout_rate):
        super(FFNNModel, self).__init__()
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.dropout_rate = dropout_rate
        self.drop_layer = nn.Dropout(p=self.dropout_rate)
        self.fully = nn.ModuleList()
        current_dim = input_dim
        for h_dim in hidden_dim:
            self.fully.append(nn.Linear(current_dim, h_dim))
            current_dim = h_dim
        self.fully.append(nn.Linear(current_dim, output_dim))

    def forward(self, x):
        for layer in self.fully[:-1]:
            x = self.drop_layer(F.relu(layer(x)))
        x = F.softmax(self.fully[-1](x), dim=0)
        return x
```

I was hoping simply putting this before training would work:

```
model = FFNNModel(30,5,[100,200,300,100],0.2)
regularizer = _Regularizer(model)
regularizer = L1Regularizer(regularizer, lambda_reg=0.1)
```

with

```
out = model(inputs)
loss = criterion(out, target) + regularizer.__add_l1()
```

Does anyone understand how to apply these 'ready to use' classes?

Comment: You might want to consider adding your **"EDIT / SIMPLE SOLUTION"** as an answer to the question, instead of including it in the question body itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pytorch: how to add L1 regularizer to activations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641976/pytorch-how-to-add-l1-regularizer-to-activations)

Comment: Please do not include the answer in the question; post a separate answer instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't run the code in question, so please reach back if something doesn't exactly work. Generally, I would say that the code you linked is needlessly complicated (it may be because it tries to be generic and allow all the following kinds of regularization). The way it is to be used is, I suppose

```
model = FFNNModel(30,5,[100,200,300,100],0.2)
regularizer = L1Regularizer(model, lambda_reg=0.1)
```

and then

```
out = model(inputs)
loss = criterion(out, target) + regularizer.regularized_all_param(0.)
```

You can check that `regularized_all_param` will just [iterate](https://github.com/dizam92/pyTorchReg/blob/master/src/regularization/regularizer.py#L34) over parameters of your model and if their name ends with `weight`, it will accumulate their sum of absolute values. For some reason the buffer is to be manually initialized, that's why we pass in the `0.`.

Really though, if you wish to efficiently regularize L1 and don't need any bells and whistles, the more manual approach, akin to your first link, will be more readable. It would go like this

```
l1_regularization = 0.
for param in model.parameters():
    l1_regularization += param.abs().sum()
loss = criterion(out, target) + l1_regularization
```

This is really what is at heart of both approaches. You use the [`Module.parameters`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.parameters) method to iterate over all model parameters and you sum up their L1 norms, which then becomes a term in your loss function. That's it. The repo you linked comes up with some fancy machinery to abstract it away but, judging by your question, fails :)

Answer (score 1):

SIMPLE SOLUTION for anyone stumbling over this:

There were always some issues with the Regularizer_ classes in the link above so i solved the issue using regular functions, adding an orthogonal regularizer as well:

```
def l1_regularizer(model, lambda_l1=0.01):
    lossl1 = 0
    for model_param_name, model_param_value in model.named_parameters():
            if model_param_name.endswith('weight'):
                lossl1 += lambda_l1 * model_param_value.abs().sum()
    return lossl1    
        
def orth_regularizer(model, lambda_orth=0.01):
    lossorth = 0
    for model_param_name, model_param_value in model.named_parameters():
            if model_param_name.endswith('weight'):
                param_flat = model_param_value.view(model_param_value.shape[0], -1)
                sym = torch.mm(param_flat, torch.t(param_flat))
                sym -= torch.eye(param_flat.shape[0])
                lossorth += lambda_orth * sym.sum()
    return lossorth
```

and during training do:

```
loss = criterion(outputs, y_data)\
      +l1_regularizer(model, lambda_l1=lambda_l1)\
      +orth_regularizer(model, lambda_orth=lambda_orth)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply L1 regularization to the loss function with the following code:

```py
loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)
l1_lambda = 0.001
l1_norm = sum(p.abs().sum() for p in model.parameters())

loss = loss + l1_lambda*l1_norm
```

---

Source: [*Deep Learning with PyTorch*](https://pytorch.org/assets/deep-learning/Deep-Learning-with-PyTorch.pdf) (8.5.2)

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent to the overly complicated regularizer code from the module you referenced:

```py
l1_loss = lambda_reg * sum([weight.abs().sum()
  for name, weight in model.named_parameters()
   if name.endswith('weight')])
loss = criterion(out, target) + l1_loss
```