# Cross Regularization between two Neural Networks

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, loss-function

I am trying to add a loss term to regularise between two neural networks and make them as similar as possible while still performing different tasks. The closes I could find is the answers in this post:
[Pytorch: how to add L1 regularizer to activations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641976/pytorch-how-to-add-l1-regularizer-to-activations)

But trying the solutions I could not get it to work. The model trains both models to a good accuracy, but ignores the regularization ( even if set to an insanely high value ), and the difference between the two only ever seems to go up. Is there something else I need to do with the additional regularization loss term to make it so that it is not ignored?

My current best attempt is shown here:

```
def train_combined(nets, dataset_train, dataset_test, num_epochs, alpha=0):
  criterion = nn.L1Loss()
  optimizers = [optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.01, momentum=0.9 ) for net in nets]
  trainloader = DataLoader(dataset_train, batch_size=32, shuffle=True )

  train_losses = []
  test_losses  = []

  for epoch in range(num_epochs):  # loop over the dataset multiple times

    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
      # get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
      inputs, *labels = data
      inputs = inputs

      # get the average of the paramaters between the two networks
      with t.no_grad():
        params = t.stack([t.cat(tuple(t.flatten(p.data) for p in net.parameters())) for net in nets])
        avg = t.sum(params, dim=0)*0.5

      # keep track of loss for both models
      all_losses = np.zeros( 2 )
      all_reg_losses = np.zeros( 2 )
      all_final_losses = np.zeros( 2 )

      # forward + backward + optimize
      for i, (net, optimizer, label) in enumerate(zip(nets, optimizers, labels)):
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # calculate normal loss
        outputs = net(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, label)        
        
        # calculate regularization loss loss
        params = t.cat(tuple(t.flatten(p.data) for p in net.parameters()))
        regularization_loss = t.sum(t.abs( params - avg ))
        regularization =  regularization_loss * alpha
        
        # calculate total loss
        final_loss = loss + regularization
        final_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # keep track of losses
        all_losses[i] = float( loss.item() )
        all_reg_losses[i] = float( 0 if (regularization == 0) else regularization.item() )
        all_final_losses[i] = float( final_loss.item() )
      
      # keep track of performance
      train_losses.append( loss )
      with t.no_grad():
        for i in range(2):
          test_losses.append( light_eval( nets[i], data_test, index=i ) )

    # log performance each epoch
    for i in range(2):
      print("%3d" % (epoch+1),  i, ':',
            f'  train loss  = { ("%.4f "*3) % (all_losses[i], all_reg_losses[i], all_final_losses[i]) }',
            f', test_losses = { "%.4f" % test_losses[-(2-i)] }')
    

  print('Finished Training')

models = [ Net().to(device) for i in range(2) ]
train_combined( models, dataset_train, dataset_test, 50, alpha=1e-2 )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved. The issue seems to come from using `p.data` instead of `p` when getting `params`.

The working solution looks like this:

```
params = t.cat(tuple(t.flatten(p) for p in net.parameters()))
assert params.requires_grad

distance = criterion(params, avg)
regularization_loss = t.sum( distance )
```