# Lack of Sparse Solution with L1 Regularization in Pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, pytorch, regularized

I am trying to implement L1 regularization onto the first layer of a simple neural network (1 hidden layer). I looked into some other posts on StackOverflow that apply l1 regularization using Pytorch to figure out how it should be done (references: [Adding L1/L2 regularization in PyTorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42704283/adding-l1-l2-regularization-in-pytorch), [In Pytorch, how to add L1 regularizer to activations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641976/in-pytorch-how-to-add-l1-regularizer-to-activations)). No matter how high I increase lambda (the l1 regularization strength parameter) I do not get true zeros in the first weight matrix. Why would this be? (Code is below)

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np

class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,nf,nh,nc):
        super(Network,self).__init__()
        self.lin1=nn.Linear(nf,nh)
        self.lin2=nn.Linear(nh,nc)

    def forward(self,x):
        l1out=F.relu(self.lin1(x))
        out=F.softmax(self.lin2(l1out))
        return out, l1out

def l1loss(layer):
    return torch.norm(layer.weight.data, p=1)

nf=10
nc=2
nh=6
learningrate=0.02
lmbda=10.
batchsize=50

net=Network(nf,nh,nc)

crit=nn.MSELoss()
optimizer=torch.optim.Adagrad(net.parameters(),lr=learningrate)


xtr=torch.Tensor(xtr)
ytr=torch.Tensor(ytr)
#ytr=torch.LongTensor(ytr)
xte=torch.Tensor(xte)
yte=torch.LongTensor(yte)
#cyte=torch.Tensor(yte)

it=200
for epoch in range(it):
    per=torch.randperm(len(xtr))
    for i in range(0,len(xtr),batchsize):
        ind=per[i:i+batchsize]
        bx,by=xtr[ind],ytr[ind]            
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output, l1out=net(bx)
#        l1reg=l1loss(net.lin1)    
        loss=crit(output,by)+lmbda*l1loss(net.lin1)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    print('Epoch [%i/%i], Loss: %.4f' %(epoch+1,it, np.float32(loss.data.numpy())))

corr=0
tot=0
for x,y in list(zip(xte,yte)):
    output,_=net(x)
    _,pred=torch.max(output,-1)
    tot+=1 #y.size(0)
    corr+=(pred==y).sum()
print(corr)
```

Note: The data has 10 features (2 classes and 800 training samples) and only the first 2 are relevant (by design) so one would assume true zeros should be easy enough to learn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your usage of `layer.weight.data` removes the parameter (which is a PyTorch variable) from its automatic differentiation context, making it a constant when the optimiser takes the gradients. This results in zero gradients and that the L1 loss is not computed.

If you remove the `.data`, the norm is computed of the PyTorch variable and the gradients should be correct.

For more information on PyTorch's automatic differentiation mechanics, see this [docs article](http://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html) or this [tutorial](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html).

Comment: I was able to get zeros by correcting that. Not in the places I would think though. Oh well. Seems like I just am not going to get results similar to what I would get with l1 regularized logistic regression.